# Third-party service for sharing files with clients

Tags: web-apps, file-management, sharing

I work for medium/large corporations and I would like a service with which I can share data with my clients.

It should be able to do those things:

- Send data to, and receive data from my clients (the corporations)
- Simple dashboard for exchanging short messages / announcing things
- Data should be stored securely and not be available publicly
- A single account for me
- Seperate accounts for my clients
- The data that is shared between me and a client should only be visible to me and that client, clients should only have access to their own data and not to other clients' data
- User rights management for my clients' accounts (so the CEO of a corporation sees all the data, but his/her subordinates see only parts of the data)

Which service would you recommend me?

Comment: Now-a-days it can be done easily with cloud there are many services available.

Answer (score 2):

Any cloud storage service should be able to provide these features.

Google Drive = fairly ubiquitous, particularly for those with Android devices, which tie into Google accounts.

OneDrive = same potential benefits as G-Drive, except replace Google with Microsoft, so it's tuned more for Windows-platform business users.

DropBox = probably the oldest and longest standing big-name cloud storage service. Still around and still heavily used, even with the others gaining popularity.

It also depends upon the nature of the content being shared. If you work with music files, for example, you may consider SoundCloud. Other formats tend to relate to other cloud services as well, such as images (photos), movies, 3D printing files, etc.